# Does the main hero level affect relic count when prestiging?

Tags: tap-titans

When you prestige, does the main character level boost to the number of relics you gain ? If so, how much ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No.

From [wikia](http://tap-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Prestige) :

> Hero levels bonus: 1 relic = 1000 hero levels.
>
> *Note: **The level of your Main Hero does not contribute to the total hero levels**. You can check the total hero levels on the statistics page in your settings.*

Comment: Huh, last time I looked at that wiki page it didn't say that (although that was a while ago). Thanks!

Comment: I think the main hero level counted before v2.0.1 : http://tap-titans.wikia.com/wiki/Changelog#Android